# send password as command via Telnet in C#

Tags: c#, telnet

I want to connect to a cisco switch via telnet in c#.I want to send commands in cmd with c# and when it asks for password I want to enter it with my program. But my problem is that I can’t send password when it is connected to telnet.And when I used StreamWriter it throws an exception.
Here is my code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string data = "";  
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\Windows\System32");  
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Windows\System32");  
        IPAddress address = IPAddress.Parse("172.16.0.110");  
        IPEndPoint ipe = new IPEndPoint(address, 23);  
        Socket telnetSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);  
        telnetSocket.Connect(ipe);  
        NetworkStream NsStream = new NetworkStream(telnetSocket, true);  
        if (telnetSocket.Connected)  
        {  
            NsStream = new NetworkStream(telnetSocket, true);  
            reader = new StreamReader(NsStream);  
        }  

        while (!reader.EndOfStream)  
        {  
            data = reader.ReadLine();  
            if (data.Contains("Password:"))  
            {  
                //I want to enter password in cmd here  
            }  
        }  
        reader.Close();  
        if (NsStream == null)  
            NsStream.Close();  
    }
}
```

Comment: .... what exception is thrown?

Comment: Have you considered using a `TcpClient` to maybe simplify things? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you use a lib like [SSH.NET](https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET) you get all these problems solved for you and no need to reinvent the wheel again!

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to talk Telnet. Telnet rfcs will give you an idead what you're dealing with. https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc854

If you want to hand-roll this, a few suggestions that might help. Or else show why it might be a good idea to use a telnet library.

- TcpClient will reduce your work a little. At least it will create the NetworkStream for you.
- You can probably ignore much of the protocol details, but not the initial option negotiation. You probably want to deal with the raw NetworkStream initially, because telnet sessions start with 'option' negotiation. A quick search for telnet option negotiation turns this up: [How to deal with the telnet negotiation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3618578/how-to-deal-with-the-telnet-negotiation)

There are two problems using the reader/writer above:

- They will be using UTF8 encoding by default, so the telnet option negotiation data (which isn't 7 bit ASCII) will likely get mutated.
- Readline() will probably hang anyway, as it will read the telnet options, which are the first thing sent by the server, but then keeping trying to read until the first end of line ... which will never arrive because the server is waiting for a response to the options it sent. i.e. you need to finish the telnet option negotiation.